# Windows 2008 TCP Performance

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, tcp, tcpip

Some background...

I am currently building a domain drop catch application using C#. It uses a single Socket, which sends data through an SslStream. I have spent weeks on the app and I am 100% sure that I have done everything I can do to make it as quick as possible. I am working against some benchmarks and currently I am 15ms of target.

My thinking...

So, I am now looking at what else could be effecting the speed of the app. It is running on a high spec machine, which is 3 hops away from the server. My thinking is that I need to start looking at the OS network settings.

Where should I start...

I am running Windows 2008 standard edition. What tweaks can I make to start speeding up the OS network? I have no control over the hardware or network.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen Microsoft's Win2008 [performance tuning guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/Perf_tun_srv.mspx) for developers?  Pages 11-15 cover network tuning, and there's lots of other good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some antivirus software on the windows machine checking the network traffic (and making it slower).

Answer (score 0):

There are too many open questions to give a real helpful answer (how do you measure latency, what kind of traffic, packet size, physical distance to target server, nature of traffic, etc.)

No. 1 Reason for higher than expected latency is that you didn't turn off the Nagle algorithm

Also, test the performance between the source and target machine using iperf (http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php)